# can't login to facebook with parse

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I'm trying to add the facebook login option to my website and i want to login to the parse account.

I've added the followed scripts:

1) after the  tag inside index.html:

```
<script>
  // Initialize Parse
  Parse.initialize("**********************", "*****************************");

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
      appId      : '{******************}', // Facebook App ID
      status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
      version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
    });

        // Run code after the Facebook SDK is loaded.

  };

      (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

2)log in function inside login.js:

```
function LogInWithFacebook(){

Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    if (!user.existed()) {
      alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
      alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
  }
});
}
```

and of course this two lines in the  tag in index.html:

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src='login.js'></script>
```

3) and than i have a simple a tag which have an onClick attribute:

```
<a href="#" onClick="LogInWithFacebook();">Log In</a>
```

However, when i click on it, nothing happens, none of the messages inside LogInWithFacebook function appears. In face, none of the messages inside `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn` appears, cause when i alert a message before i call `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn` it appears...

Comment: When you use facebook api there should not be any problems since their documentation is pretty good. Also use OAuth2.

Comment: That code works fine for me, can you provide a link to a demo or a jsfiddle?